# How can I get pianobarfly to compile correctly on OS X?

Tags: macos, makefile, pthreads, homebrew, pandora

I'm trying to get [pianobarfly](https://github.com/ghuntley/pianobarfly) working on OS X and can't get it to compile correctly.

Selected text from the install document:

```
Dependencies
------------

gmake
libao               http://www.xiph.org/ao/
libfaad2            http://www.audiocoding.com/downloads.html
AND/OR libmad       http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/
pthreads
libid3tag           http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/
UTF-8 console/locale!



Building
--------

If you have all of the dependencies listed above just type

    make clean && make

NOTE: The above won't work on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) since c99 targets i386
and cc (gcc4.2) targets x86_64. If you've built supporting libraries
(libao, etc.) using gcc, you'll be unable to link. You can work around
this issue by overriding CFLAGS[1]

    make clean && make CFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG -W64" && make DISABLE_FAAD=1
```

I think I have all the dependencies, except I'm not sure if I have `pthreads` or not, and I'm assuming my system default is `UTF-8 console/locale!`

I have used homebrew to install the dependencies I didn't have, like `faad2` and `libid3tag`, but I haven't been to turn up anything on google about installing `pthreads` or how to tell if I have that already or not.

Anyhow, when I try to complile pianobarfly, this is what I get:

```
####:pianobarfly user$ make clean && make CFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG -W64" && make DISABLE_FAAD=1
rm -f src/main.o src/player.o src/settings.o src/terminal.o src/ui_act.o src/ui.o\
src/ui_readline.o src/ui_dispatch.o src/fly.o src/fly_id3.o src/fly_mp4.o\
src/libpiano/crypt.o src/libpiano/piano.o src/libpiano/xml.o\
src/libwaitress/waitress.o src/libwaitress/waitress.o/test.o \
            src/libezxml/ezxml.o src/libpiano/crypt.lo src/libpiano/piano.lo\
          src/libpiano/xml.lo src/libwaitress/waitress.lo \
            src/libezxml/ezxml.lo pianobarfly libpiano.so* libpiano.a waitress-test
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/main.o src/main.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/player.o src/player.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/settings.o src/settings.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/terminal.o src/terminal.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/ui_act.o src/ui_act.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/ui.o src/ui.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/ui_readline.o src/ui_readline.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/ui_dispatch.o src/ui_dispatch.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/fly.o src/fly.c
src/fly.c: In function ‘_BarFlyParseCoverArtURL’:
src/fly.c:733: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strndup’
src/fly.c:734: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/fly_id3.o src/fly_id3.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/fly_mp4.o src/fly_mp4.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/libpiano/crypt.o src/libpiano/crypt.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/libpiano/piano.o src/libpiano/piano.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/libpiano/xml.o src/libpiano/xml.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/libwaitress/waitress.o src/libwaitress/waitress.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64 -I src/libpiano -I src/libwaitress \
            -I src/libezxml -DENABLE_FAAD \
            -DENABLE_MAD -DENABLE_ID3TAG -c -o src/libezxml/ezxml.o src/libezxml/ezxml.c
c99 -O2 -DNDEBUG -W64  src/main.o src/player.o src/settings.o src/terminal.o src/ui_act.o\
    src/ui.o src/ui_readline.o src/ui_dispatch.o src/fly.o src/fly_id3.o src/fly_mp4.o\
    src/libpiano/crypt.o src/libpiano/piano.o src/libpiano/xml.o \
            src/libwaitress/waitress.o src/libezxml/ezxml.o -lao -lpthread -lm \
            -lfaad -lmad -lid3tag -o pianobarfly
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_strndup", referenced from:
      _BarFlyOpen in fly.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pianobarfly] Error 1
####:pianobarfly user$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved within the master and development branch of pianobarfly. Please be aware that there is an issue/patch available for homebrew which resolves a issue where pkg-config was not being generated for id3tag.pc. This patch has not (yet) been integrated into homebrew.

See: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/7973

Also see: https://github.com/ghuntley/pianobarfly/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

This is a portability bug in the program you are trying to build: it assumes that `strndup()` is available, and it isn't.

Fortunately, it's trivial to implement your own `strndup` replacement, given a [description](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strndup) of what it does.

Or you may check `fly.c`: perhaps replacing `strndup` with `strdup` also works.